# What are the risk of floating a solid hardwood above grade floor using a clip system?

Tags: concrete, installation, hardwood-floor, subfloor

I have been mired in this rabbit hole of picking a flooring for my new condo. I cannot glue or nail into concrete so I either I double floor it with plywood then hardood or I float. I have been reading how solid wood floors cannot be floated as commandment. Then I stumble across this company Junckers that offers a clip system that allows floating of hardwood over concrete 
[Junckers Clip System](http://www.junckershardwood.com/commercial/floors/installation/clip-system.aspx).

I wondering how bad things can get if I ensure proper expansion spacing and humidity control of an above grade floor. I will have a moisture barrier down as well.

I wanted to get opinion of this particular scenario and if anyone had any experience working with the Junckers system.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A product called 'DRIcore' (or similar) would work. DRIcore comes as 2ft x 2ft tongue-and-groove panels made from OSB with a solid plastic bottom. You fit them/install them on top of your substrate (concrete in this case), and then the material they're made of can be nailed into.

http://www.homedepot.com/p/DRIcore-7-8-in-x-2-ft-x-2-ft-DRIcore-Subfloor-Panel-CDGNUS750024024/202268752

Comment: I confirm that I have seen Dricore used with laminate and hardwood over concrete floors in basements.  Works great but a water flood is still a rebuild even with the plastic bottom.

Comment: @kevinsky How high does it raise the floor, do I have to worry about doors and the like?

Comment: @TheCodeNovice total height is around one inches. Not a problem with doors unless you are very tall.  Could be tricky for your use where you transition to other areas where it concrete + carpet and one inche lower

Comment: @kevinsky Can these things be cut or am I stuck with the square shapes?

Comment: @TheCodeNovice Sure you can cut them with a circular saw or jigsaw, complex shapes are harder to cut.